# jQuery Radio Button "is selected" code

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am writing a program to check if a radio button is selected. What I have is a good start but I could use a little help fully implementing this type of radio button code. The div's are not quite toggling just yet.

```
<?php
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#enteraddress').toggle();
$('#entercoords').toggle();
//$('#enteraddress').click(function () { $('#enteraddress').hide(); });
    if ($('#byaddress:checked').val() == 'true') {         
        $('#enteraddress').toggle();
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style='border: solid 1px black; margin-bottom: 10px;' id="legaldisclaimer">
<h1>Legal Disclaimer:</h1>
<p>Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.
Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war.
We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live.
It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate -- we can not consecrate -- we can not hallow -- this ground.
The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract.
The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here.
It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced.
It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us --
that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion --
that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain -- that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom --
and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.</p>
</body>
</div>
<div style='border: solid 1px black; margin-bottom: 10px;' id="locationoptions">
<h3>How would you like to enter your location data?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="locationradios" id="byaddress">By physichal address?</input></br>
<input type="radio" name="locationradios" id="bylatlng">By latitude and longitude?</input>
</div>
<div style='border: solid 1px black; margin-bottom: 10px;' id="enteraddress">
<h3>Radio 1</h3>
</div>
<div style='border: solid 1px black;' id="entercoords">
<h3>Radio 2</h3>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try using:

```
$("input").is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 4):

`$("selector").is(':checked')` returns a *boolean*. So you can do:

```
if ( $("#byaddress").is(':checked') == true ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `== true` is redundant inside an `if` statement. Plus you should use `===`anyway.

Comment: True. Makes is a bit clearer when explaining to someone still learning though. I wouldn't include the == true myself :-)
Why the ===?

Comment: Strict type checking -- http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/comparison_operators.html

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your if condition as

```
if($("input[type='radio']:checked").attr('id') == "byaddress"){
  $('#enteraddress').toggle();
}
```

instead of

```
if ($('#byaddress:checked').val() == 'true') {         
        $('#enteraddress').toggle();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#enteraddress').hide();
$('#entercoords').hide();
$('#theyellow').hide();

$("#radio01").click(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) { $('#enteraddress').show(); $('#theyellow').show(); $('#entercoords').hide();  }
});

$("#radio02").click(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) { $('#entercoords').show(); $('#theyellow').show(); $('#enteraddress').hide();  }
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="mymapgetter" action="action.php">
<div style='border: solid 1px black; margin-bottom: 10px;' id="legaldisclaimer">
<h1>Legal Disclaimer:</h1>
<p>Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.
Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war.
We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live.
It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate -- we can not consecrate -- we can not hallow -- this ground.
The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract.
The world will little note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here.
It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced.
It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us --
that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion --
that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain -- that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom --
and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.</p>
</body>
</div>
<div style='border: solid 1px black; margin-bottom: 10px;' id="locationoptions">
<h3>How would you like to enter your location data?</h3>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="" id="radio01">By physichal address?</input></br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="" id="radio02">By latitude and longitude?</input>
</div>
<div style='border: solid 1px black; margin-bottom: 10px;' id="enteraddress">
<h3>Enter your physichal address:</h3></br>
<input type="text" name="theaddress" value="" style="width: 100%;"></input>
</div>
<div style='border: solid 1px black;' id="entercoords">
<h3>Enter your latitude and longitude:</h3>
<input type="text" name="thelat" value=""><- Lat.</input><input type="text" name="thelng" value=""><- Lng.</input>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="theyellow" value="getmap" style="width: 100%"></input>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I looped through a set of input elements (this) and built a string that I then used to get the value of the 'name' (for form input)

This is the only way I found to get the value of what was clicked in a radio button.  Of course a form post would do the same thing but I could not actually do the submit.

```
var findit = "input:radio[name=" + $(this).attr("name") + "]:checked";
console.log($(findit).val());
```